# Fetch logo and color from url

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am building a project management system, and there is an option for the client to change the logo, primary, and secondary colors of the web app by entering their website URL into an input field, When he click save, it will grab the logo, primary, and secondary colors from the URL the client entered and set it in the web app.
Can anyone provide me a hint on how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot

```
<input v-model="websiteUrl" type="text" placeholder="Enter website URL">

<button @click="fetchWebsiteDetails">Save</button>

<div v-if="faviconUrl">

  <img :src="faviconUrl" alt="Website Favicon">

</div>

<div v-if="primaryColor">Primary Color: {{ primaryColor }}</div>

<div v-if="secondaryColor">Secondary Color: {{ secondaryColor }}</div>
```

Comment: you'll need to write a function `fetchWebsiteDetails` for a start.

Comment: You will need a proxy on the server for that. You will likely run into CORS errors if you try on the client in the browser.